# Different behaviour of time.sleep() in python 2 and python 3

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x, timing

I use a time.sleep(0.0000001) in loops in a multithreading application because otherwise it won't respond to a thread.interrupt_main() invoked in a backdoor server thread.

I wanted the sleep to be as short as possible in order for the task to run as fast as possible, yet to be still responsive to the interrupt.

It worked fine with python 2.7 (2.7.9 / Anaconda 2.2.0). Using it with python 3.5.1 (Anaconda 4.1.0) on the same machine, it lasted much longer, slowing everything down significantly.
Further investigations in ipython showed the following in python 2

```
%timeit time.sleep(0.0000001)
```

resulted in: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 3.72 µs per loop

```
%timeit time.sleep(0.000000)
```

resulted in: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 3.86 µs per loop

In python 3 this was different:

```
%timeit time.sleep(0.0000001)
```

resulted in: 100 loops, best of 3: 4 ms per loop

```
%timeit time.sleep(0.000000)
```

resulted in: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 7.87 µs per loop

I know about the system dependent resolution of time.sleep() which is definitly larger that the 0.0000001. So what I'm using is basically calling time.sleep() as an interrupt.

- What explains the difference of about 1000 times between python 2 and python 3?
- Can it be changed?
- Is there an alternative possibility to make an application/thread more repsonsive to thread.interrupt_main()?

**Edit:**
My first aproach of reducing the time parameter showed a time reduction in python 2 for values less than 0.000001, which didn't work in python 3.
A value of 0 seems to work now for both versions.

Comment: aren't you happy with `timeit time.sleep(0.000000)` in python 3 ? 7 microseconds is getting dangerously close to an active/100% CPU loop. If you don't mind an active loop, do one. Nanosleep is not planned: https://bugs.python.org/issue13981

Comment: I can live with it. My further investigations showed, that (at least on my system) there seems to be a quantisation step of 4ms. The only difference being that in python 2.7 values less than 0.000001 return in about 3µs and in python3 this works only for a value of zero.